# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "cms_cmsplugin" already exists

Tags: python, django, migration, django-cms

While upgrading an old project to django 1.8 and djangocms 3.5 I am getting an error that says:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "cms_cmsplugin" already
>   exists

Does anyone understand what is wrong and can help with that? 
Thanks.

I have tried some solution propositions on other titles but none worked. 
did `--fake-initial`, tried migrating commenting out all other plugins of cms etc but none worked.

Comment: trace the migration file raising the error delete the code `cms_cmsplugin.CreateModel(...)` part from list

Answer (score 1):

I can only give little advice on your specific error: The table cms_cmsplugin" is already existing. But I guess you can read errors...starting with a fresh db could be a solution (restarting the upgrade process, with the orignal db from before the upgrade). I can give some general advice for upgrading django/django-cms projects.

Key point for me always was: make it reproducable. So you can try things, but also start over again, without much of an effort. I for myself once made a tool for this purpose: [project-updater](https://github.com/benzkji/project-updater). I normaly had scripts to automatically reset db and media files and git tag to the starting point of my upgrade, then execute steps required up to where I was currently stuck, and from there move on...wether using project updater, your own workflow, or another tool is not of that importance...